# Set default from address based on To address in Exchange Office 365

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, office365, exchange

Is there a way that, inside Exchange for Office365 I can set an incoming email to have a specific "Reply From" address for my clients?

I'll explain, let's say there are a collection of email accounts for all the US states, washington@domain.com, texas@domain.com etc.

All these are picked up and placed in a shared mailbox let's call states@domain.com
If an email is sent to washington@domain.com how can I set this for my clients to automatically reply from washington@domain.com?

I would rather like to avoid coding in this instance if possible as there are multiple users that need this setup.

Is this possible?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Are the additional addresses aliases on the shared mailbox, or are they separate mailboxes?

Comment: @Cpt.Whale The individual emails are shared mailboxes themselves so they are actually capable of sending out and users have those permissions, however, Exchange intercepts them with a Rule that redirects any incoming email to the states@ mailbox instead.

Comment: Are you asking about the `Reply-To` email header (as distinct from the `Sender` header)?

Comment: @harrymc Not the Reply-To, I would like to adjust the default email that is used as the From address based on the initial address the email was sent to. It's a little unorthodox I'll admit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, if you want email addresses to behave like separate mailboxes, keep them separate. Exchange rewrites the sent-to address on redirected email, so there's not an option to automatically do what you're looking for, even with code/add-ins.

If each address belongs to a separate mailbox, then it's easiest to keep the email messages stored in those mailboxes and delegate permissions. Outlook clients will reply from the correct mailbox based on the sent-to address. Typically a user would need to load all the shared mailboxes, and optionally use something like a search folder across all mailboxes to work on everything in one view.

Or, if messages need to go to a single mailbox, then it's better to set each address up as an alias for that one mailbox instead of redirecting. In O365 Exchange and newer versions of Outlook, those aliases can be used as sent-from addresses:

1. [SendFromAliasEnabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/set-organizationconfig?view=exchange-ps#-sendfromaliasenabled) must enabled in Exchange,
2. Users will need to enable each alias in Outlook on the web under Settings > View all Outlook settings > Compose and Reply, and enable each address they want to use as sent-from addresses. They may still have to choose the From address manually the first time it's used.

Here's a detailed walkthrough with screenshots: https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/office-365-exchange-send-proxy-addresses/

If neither is an option for you, then yes you probably need to find/develop an outlook add-in to dig for the original sent-to address and attempt to set it as the From address on new messages.

Comment: I had a feeling this wasn't simple, unfortunately with approaching 20 mailboxes the client's Outlook is very overbearing. Having to adjust multiple registry entries just so they can search and also add the full amount (this is for multiple users)
Thank you for the information, I'm not sure SendFromAliases will be the solution so may need to write something up.